# HTML Canvas - background eraser not working on a single click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas

I'm working on a background remover app using html5 canvas and angularJS. I'm stacking two canvases and removing pixels from the top one using a custom cursor which corresponds to the size of the eraser. I have a really strange bug which only allows me to delete the foreground if I move my mouse quickly, single clicks and slow mouse movement doesn't affect the canvas. I suspect there is a problem with angular even listeners as the same version of the code which I ran using liveServer in vscode and standard JS event listeners `canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', erase);` worked fine. Any help on this will be appreciated.

I'm working on a codepen to better illustrate the issue.

Markup:

```
<div class="cursor" ng-mousemove="erase($event)"
     ng-mousedown="startPosition($event)"
     ng-mouseup="finishedPosition($event)"><!-- -->
    <!--ng-click="cursorMove($event)"-->
    <span class="innerCursor"></span>
</div>

<div class="canvas-container" ng-init="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="z-index: 2;" ng-mousemove="erase($event);"
            ng-mousedown="startPosition($event)"
            ng-mouseup="finishedPosition($event)"></canvas>
    <canvas id="bgCanvas" style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//Gets real mouse position in canvas
function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), // abs. size of element
        scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width,    // relationship bitmap vs. element for X
        scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;  // relationship bitmap vs. element for Y

    return {
        x: (e.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX,   // scale mouse coordinates after they have
        y: (e.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY     // been adjusted to be relative to element
    }
}

//Controls the movement of the custom cursor 
$scope.cursorMove = function (x, y) {
    var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
    cursor.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + $scope.options.brushSize + 'px; height: ' + $scope.options.brushSize + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px; transform : translate(-' + 50 + '%, -' + 50 + '%)' + ';');
}

$scope.init = function () {
    //Foreground
    $scope.canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    $scope.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //Background
    $scope.bgCanvas = document.querySelector('#bgCanvas');
    $scope.ctxBg = bgCanvas.getContext('2d');

    $scope.ctx.canvas.height = 600;
    $scope.ctx.canvas.width = 900;

    $scope.drawAll();
}

//Display all elements
$scope.drawAll = function () {
    $scope.drawForeground();
    $scope.drawBackground();
}

$scope.drawForeground = function () {
    console.log('foreground');
    var url = $scope.personalisationOptions.noBackgroundImage;
    //var url = 'img link';
    var img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = url + '?' + new Date().getTime();
    img1.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
    img1.onload = function () {
        $scope.ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, $scope.ctx.canvas.clientWidth, $scope.ctx.canvas.clientHeight);
    }
}

$scope.drawBackground = function () {
    console.log('background');
    var img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = 'img link';
    img2.onload = function () {
        $scope.ctxBg.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, $scope.ctx.canvas.clientWidth, $scope.ctx.canvas.clientHeight);
    }
}

//Erasing functionality
$scope.erasing = false;

$scope.erase = function (e) {

    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    $scope.cursorMove(pos.x, pos.y);

    if (!$scope.erasing) return;

    if (!$scope.pendingSnapshot) {
        $scope.pendingSnapshot = $scope.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    if ($scope.options.isCircle) {
        console.log('B');
        // circular eraser
        $scope.ctx.save();
        $scope.ctx.beginPath();
        $scope.ctx.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, $scope.options.brushSize / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        $scope.ctx.clip();
        //eraser with new coordinates pos.x / pos.y
        $scope.ctx.clearRect(pos.x - $scope.options.brushSize, pos.y - $scope.options.brushSize, $scope.options.brushSize * 2, $scope.options.brushSize * 2);
        console.log(pos.x, pos.y - $scope.options.brushSize);
        $scope.ctx.restore();
    } else {
        // square eraser
        $scope.ctx.beginPath();
        $scope.ctx.clearRect(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, $scope.options.brushSize, $scope.options.brushSize);
    }
}

$scope.startPosition = function (e) {
    $scope.erasing = true;
    $scope.erase(e);
    console.log('mouse down');
}

$scope.finishedPosition = function () {
    $scope.erasing = false;
    console.log('mouse up');
    $scope.ctx.beginPath();
    $scope.imageSnapshot = $scope.pendingSnapshot;

    //limit clickHistory to 5
    if ($scope.clickHistory.length > 4) {
        $scope.clickHistory.shift();
    }

    $scope.clickHistory.push($scope.pendingSnapshot);
    $scope.pendingSnapshot = null;
}
```

Comment: Could you add drawAll and getMousePos functions?

Comment: added both functions

Comment: Another not defined function. Could you adjust this fiddle to your purpose https://jsfiddle.net/6ug932hq/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adammo14/2ypkfs1h/9/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my custom cursor that was causing the issue. The cursor div was sitting in front of the canvas and was preventing the erase function to work correctly because it never had access to the canvas. This explains why erase only worked when I moved my mouse quickly. The actual cursor was getting ahead of the custom one.

I'm now using svg cursor solution from this post: [Dynamically change SVG cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285114/dynamically-change-svg-cursor)